# Java - Type mismatch (But both are from same type?!): cannot convert from HashMap<Integer,ArrayList<Integer>> to HashMap<Integer,ArrayList<Integer>>

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, maps

---

EDIT: problem is solved: see the answer of Karim SNOUSSI and my comment below it.

---

this is my very first question at stack overflow, so i might won't get everything right at the beginnig. Sorry for that. In addition I'm new to java and to programming in general.

I've encountered a strange error cant't really understand what the sollution could be.

While trying to pass a hashMap from one class to another the IDE eclipse says:
**Type mismatch: cannot convert from HashMap> to HashMap>**

But both are of the same type if i get it right, so don't know what's the problem.

Here's my code: I post only part of it so not cluttering all up

I have a HashMap in my class called graph.class,
it is used in the method public HashMap> getAllShortestPaths()
where all shortest Paths from each node to any other node in the graph will be calculated
and stored into the hashMap for further processing.
Which works fine, when printig the map to the screen it displays all informations properly, if I want to do it from the method within.

But my purpose is to pass this hashMap to another class where I will collect my whole analysis of the graph and save it into a new file.

```
public class Graph {
.
.
    private HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> shortestPathsMap = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>>();
```

.
.
.

```
public HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> getShortestPathsMap() { return shortestPathsMap; }
.
.
.
    public void getAllShortestPaths() {
        for(int i = 0; i < getNodeCount(); i++) {
            ArrayList<Integer> shortestPathMapValues = new ArrayList<>();   // saves ... 

            for(int n = i; n < getNodeCount(); n++) {
                shortestPathMapValues.add(n);                               // the corresponding node id's and ..
                shortestPathMapValues.add((int) shortestPath(i,n));         // the outcome of shortestPath() calculation
            }

            shortestPathsMap.put(i, shortestPathMapValues);                 // saves the first node id and the corresponding values
        }
    }
.
.
```

So for testing i passed it to the Main.class and did want to print it to the screen:

```
public HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> getShortestPathsMap() { 
        return shortestPathsMap; 
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
.
.
.
G.getAllShortestPaths();

                    HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> spMap = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>>();
                    spMap = G.getShortestPathsMap();

                    // iterate and display values
                    for(Entry<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> entry : spMap.entrySet()) {
                        int key = entry.getKey();
                        ArrayList<Integer> values = entry.getValue();

                        System.out.println("Key = " + key);
                        System.out.println("Values = " + values);
                    }
.
.
.
```

And here in the Main.class, at the line where:
**spMap = G.getShortestPathsMap();**
The IDE displays

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from HashMap>
>   to HashMap>

But:

```
HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> spMap = new HashMap<Integer,Integer, ArrayList<Integer>>();

HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> shortestPathsMap = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>>();
```

spMap and shortestPathsMap are of the same Typ, aren't they?

I'm happy about any helpful reply and thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you post the code for `getShortestPathsMap();`?

Comment: it is just a simple getter. I tried it once with the getter method, and once with return argument in the getAllShortestPaths() method, but both not working.

Comment: Please clean up your question. Your types have all been corrupted. I see a lot of "HashMap>" which indicates that some software has tried to modify your question, perhaps for "HTML sanitization" reasons.

Comment: the code you pasted is incomplete. `G.getShortestPathsMap()` – where is "G" defined? where is "getShortestPathsMap" defined? many other things don't line up either. take a look at this: [_How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Yes unfortunately I've tryied to copy paste the code here but all the time it gets modified automatically and its messy to clean up.

Comment: G is defined in Main, i will add id to the question

Comment: Unfortunately i can not post the whole code becuase I don't own it. It is a project at the university and parts of it was written by others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace this in your main method

```
HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> spMap = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>>();
spMap = G.getShortestPathsMap();
```

with this

```
Map<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> spMap = G.getShortestPathsMap();
```

Comment: Tryied this already and did get the same Type Mismatch message unfortunately. But thank you

Comment: I don't really know what is the problem with it but try to replace it with
`spMap = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>>(G.getShortestPathsMap());`

Comment: Great, thank you so much for the hint. This worked for me: `HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> spMap = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>>(G.getShortestPathsMap());`

Comment: Unfortunately it worked first but after running the programm multiple times without any error it said suddenly: **The constructor HashMap<Integer,ArrayList<Integer>>(HashMap<Integer,ArrayList<Integer>>) is undefined**

Comment: I changed it to `HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> spMap = new HashMap(G.getShortestPathsMap());` and it works despite a warning **HashMap is a raw type. References to generic type HashMap<K,V> should be parameterized**